# Error while unmarshalling json with Jackson 2

Tags: java, json, jackson, unmarshalling, jackson2

I am trying to unmarshal the following JSON file using Jackson 2 :

```
{
  "mapID": "123",
  "objects": [
    {
      "mapID": "123",
      "objectID": "12",
      "properties": {
        "type": "2",
        "maxSpeed": "110",
        "name": "name1",
        "bridge": false
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          {
            "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
            "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
          },
          {
            "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
            "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
          },
          {
            "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
            "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
          },
          {
            "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
            "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "mapID": "123",
      "objectID": "14",
      "properties": {
        "type": "5",
        "name": "name2",
        "redLightTime": "40"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          {
            "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
            "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "mapID" : "123",
      "objectID" : "13",
      "properties" : {
        "type" : "4",
        "maxSpeed" : "40",
        "name" : "name3",
        "roundaboutLanes" : "2"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates" : [
          [
            {
              "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
              "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
            },
            {
              "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
              "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
            },
            {
              "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
              "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
            },
            {
              "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
              "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
            },
            {
              "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
              "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
            },
            {
              "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
              "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
            },
            {
              "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
              "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
            },
            {
              "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
              "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
            },
            {
              "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
              "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
            },
            {
              "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
              "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
            },
            {
              "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
              "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
            },
            {
              "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
              "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
            },
            {
              "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
              "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
            },
            {
              "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
              "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

public class MapJSON {
    private int mapID;
    private List<Objects> objects;

    public int getMapID() {
        return mapID;
    }

    public void setMapID(int mapID) {
        this.mapID = mapID;
    }

    public List<Objects> getObjects() {
        return objects;
    }

    public void setObjects(List<Objects> objects) {
        this.objects = objects;
    }
}


public class Objects {
    private int mapID;
    private int objectID;
    private Properties properties;
    private Geometry geometry;

    public int getMapID() {
        return mapID;
    }

    public void setMapID(int mapID) {
        this.mapID = mapID;
    }

    public int getObjectID() {
        return objectID;
    }

    public void setObjectID(int objectID) {
        this.objectID = objectID;
    }

    public Properties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public Geometry getGeometry() {
        return geometry;
    }

    public void setGeometry(Geometry geometry) {
        this.geometry = geometry;
    }
}


public class Geometry {

    private List<Coordinates> coordinates;

    public List<Coordinates> getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(List<Coordinates> coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }
}

public class Coordinates {

    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
```

The error occurs while unmarshalling the Geometry/coordinates elements.
Can someone point me where is the error ?

Everything is OK before the geometry part.

Answer (score 2):

In json example `coordinates` is array of array of double, but in java code it's array of objects:

You need to adjust JSON to format like next:

```
"coordinates": [
          {
            latitude : 4.54559326171875,
            longitude : 45.754109791149865
          }
        ]
```

Or consider changing you `Coordinates` class to reflect JSON structure:

```
public class Coordinates {
    private List<Double> coordinates;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my JSON  like in your comment, but I still got an error:Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of fr.enssat.lanniontech.Coordinates out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: src/test/resources/map_all.json; line: 62, column: 11] (through reference chain: fr.enssat.lanniontech.MapJSON["objects"]->java.util.ArrayList[2]->fr.enssat.lanniontech.Objects["geometry"]->fr.enssat.lanniontech.Geometry["coordinates"]

Comment: Changing `Coordinates` like that still won't parse correctly.  In the JSON, "geometry" has a "coordinates" field, but each sub array is not also named "coordinates".

Comment: @azurefrog so I don't really understand how to define my JSON or my Java objects :/

Answer (score 1):

Your class doesn't match your JSON.

Your `Coordinates` class has two double fields, `latitude` and `longitude`, which would match a JSON that looked like this:

```
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      {
        "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
        "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
      },
      ...
```

Your JSON on the other hand has the coordinates defined as a bunch of nested arrays:

```
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      [
        4.54559326171875,
        45.754109791149865
      ],
      ...
```

You need to either change your JSON to pass in the named fields, or change
your geometry class to store a nested list of double:

```
public class Geometry {

    private List<List<Double>> coordinates;
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my JSON  like in your comment, but I still got an error:Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of fr.enssat.lanniontech.Coordinates out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: src/test/resources/map_all.json; line: 62, column: 11] (through reference chain: fr.enssat.lanniontech.MapJSON["objects"]->java.util.ArrayList[2]->fr.enssat.lanniontech.Objects["geometry"]->fr.enssat.lanniontech.Geometry["coordinates"]

Comment: It looks like you've updated your code to match Tionio's answer, not mine.  There is no `Coordinates` class to deserialize if you change `Geometry` like I suggest, so you couldn't get an error saying "Can not deserialize instance of fr.enssat.lanniontech.Coordinates"

Comment: I updated the JSON, not the Java objecte. I now have my "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      {
        "latitude" : 4.54559326171875,
        "longitude" : 45.754109791149865
      },
      ...

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you, then; it works for me.

Comment: Did you tested ? Can you send me the projet Java files and JSON ? I think I'm missing something !